# Problem with acro package Latex (The key 'acro/short-format' is unknown and is being ignored. })

Tags: thesis, acro

```
\RequirePackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acro}

\acsetup{
    format = \emph,
%   format = {\textcolor{blue}},
    short-format = {\textcolor{blue}},
    templates/colspec = longtable
}
\DeclareAcronym{abc}{
    short=ABC, 
    long=Artificial Bee Colony
}

\DeclareAcronym{aco}{
    short=ACO, 
    long=Ant Colony Optimization
}

\DeclareAcronym{aes}{
    short=AES, 
    long=Advanced Encryption Standard
}

\printacronyms[heading=none, display=used, sort=true]
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top level the key to be used with `\acseutp` is `format/short`.
`short-format` is the acronym-specific equivalent available within `\DeclareAcronym`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{
    format = \emph,
    format/short = \color{blue},
}

\DeclareAcronym{abc}{
    short=ABC, 
    long=Artificial Bee Colony
}

\begin{document}
\ac{abc}
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code showing acronym usage and list of acronyms with short format printed in blue]

The package options `printonlyused` and `withpage` are also no longer accepted, by default only used acronyms will be printed, while `withpage` should be set with `pages/display=first` or `pages/display=all` passed to either `\acsetup` to act on all lists or `\printacronyms` to act on a specific list.

Comment: `\textcolor{blue}` will work here but using the switch `\color{blue}` is probably better practice.